# Uniqueness of stationary measures for $(G,\mu)$ boundaries

Tags: pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, geometric-group-theory, random-walks

Let $G$ be a countable group acting minimally by homeomorphisms on a compact Hausdorff space $X$ and $\mu$ be a probability measure on $G$ whose support generates $G$ as a semigroup.
Let $\nu$ is a $\mu$-stationary measure on $X$ such that $(X,\nu)$ is a $(G,\mu)$ boundary, ie for  $\mu^{\mathbb{N}}$ almost every trajectory $g_n$ the pushforwards $g_1...g_n \nu$ weakly converge to a dirac measure.

Does it follow that $\nu$ is the unique $\mu$-stationary Borel probability measure on $X$? This is the case in many geometric situations, for instance when the action is on the Gromov boundary of a hyperbolic group. In general I suspect the answer is false but cannot think of a counterexample...

Comment: Hi Ilya, the way you formulated the question admits trivial counter examples, such as taking $X$ to be the disjoint union of two stationary systems. Below I gave a more satisfactory counter-example. Moreover, even restricting ourselves to pmp action, basically you're asking whether every action is uniquely ergodic, which is far from being the case.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.10133 by Hartman-Kalantar, which discusses unique stationarity.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I ruled out this particular trivial counterexample by assuming the action to be minimal?

Comment: Sorry, I missed minimality... but anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to force a counter example is by taking $G$ to be an amenable group and choose $\mu$ such that the Furstenberg-Poisson boundary of $(G,\mu)$ is non-trivial.
Now take $X$ to be a compact model of this Furstenberg-Poisson boundary.
Then, by amenability, $X$ admits an invariant measure in addition to the $\nu$,
thus at least two different stationary measures.